# Implementing tree structure UITableview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

Can We create tree structure in UITableView like below.

```
-Sub1                    //First row
  -Sub1sub1              //First row's child
    -sub1sub1sub1        //Child's child etc..
    -sub1sub1sub2
  -Sun1sub2
    -sub2sub2sub1
    -sub2sub2sub2
-Sub2
  -Sub2sub1
    -sub1sub2sub1
    -sub1sub1sub2
  -Sun2sub2
    -sub2sub2sub1
    -sub2sub2sub2
```

Don't want any code but is there any reference for implementing this..or just let me know is it possible or not..

Please help me to solve this question..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got my answer..

Using this [Github link](https://github.com/seletz/CocoaTreeViewExample)

Thanks Github...

Comment: wonderful code. Any idea how i can place a `+` `-` image/icon with tree expand and collapse?

Comment: I am trying to make this tree divided in `sections`. No progress so far :(

Comment: as I see it does not embed tableView into tableViewCell

Answer (score 1):

TableView delegate method

```
   tableView:indentationLevelForRowAtIndexPath:
```

can be used to indent rows according to your needs

Answer (score 0):

I've done it before, and using this approach helped me a lot:

[Implementing UITableView Tree Structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672967/implementing-uitableview-tree-structure)

If you need help of how to implement that solution, or if it doenst fit your problem, let us know and we will help you

Edit: I just realized you have one more level of depth that the link, but in your case you can use a header for the first level)